# Bookmarks linhas específicas Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

é possível colocar bookmarks em alguma linha de código qualquer? estilo as IDEs ta Inteliji?
peguei um código legado aqui que tem 12k linhas uma classe de relatório, perco muito tempo achando os métodos principais, mesmo com o CodeMap é inviável, tem mais de duzentos métodos....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível. O atalho no teclado é CTRL+K+K. Para navegar entre os bookmarks, use CTRL+K+N para avançar para o próximo bookmark.

**Edição** Acabei de verificar que os atalhos "oficiais" são diferentes:

- CTRL+B+K para criar ou destruir bookmark;
- CTRL+B+N para ir para o próximo;
- CTRL+B+P para ir ao bookmark anterior.

Os dois atalhos que mencionei anteriormente também funcionam, mas não possuem um equivalente para ir ao bookmark anterior.

Comment: Great!!! Quase excelente, kkkk, não tem um painel para visualizar? Só o visualizar próximo (no caso o k+n)?
Ele salva isso em arquivos do projeto ou nas configurações locais do VS (para fins da equipe usar tais atalhos via repositório web em git)?

Comment: Já achei a bookmark window, kkkkk, vlw mesmo assim! sobre o salvamento, sabe?

Comment: Os bookmarks ficam num arquivo binário. Procura por um ficheiro de extensão `.suo` na sua solução ;)